# Does @aptos-labs/wallet-adapter-core have the ability to switch wallet networks?

Tags: aptos

I want to switch aptos wallet network such as Petra, But failed.

```js
const arr = [ new PetraWallet()]
const wallet = new WalletCore(arr)
wallet.connect("Petra").then(() => {
 
   // How Can I switch network from Mainnet to Devnet ?
   // TODO ....
})
```

I want the sdk can switch Petra network, such as Matemask `wallet_switchEthereumChain` method.

Answer (score 0):

The adapter doesn't support this functionality for the main reason that it requires a wallet support (i.e Petra and others need to support switch network request).

It does look like a valuable feature and we can explore adding it to the adapter!